# Help test this REST method

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api

Please help test this method
I don't undestend how testing this method

```
public static Weather getWeather(String city){
    String KEY = 'My Key';
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + '&appid='+ KEY);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setTimeout(60000);
    try{
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
        Weath w = (Weath)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), Weath.class);
        //strange, but it is necessary 
        String weather = JSON.serialize(w.weather[0]);       
        WeatherMain we = (WeatherMain)JSON.deserialize(weather, WeatherMain.class);

        Weather fullWeather = new Weather();
        fullWeather.name = w.name;
        fullWeather.country = w.sys.country;
        fullWeather.main = we.main;
        fullWeather.description = we.description;
        fullWeather.icon = we.icon;
        fullWeather.temp = temperature(w.main.temp);
        fullWeather.wind = windSpeed(w.wind.speed);
        fullWeather.humidity = w.main.humidity;
        fullWeather.pressure = w.main.pressure;
        System.debug(String.valueof(fullWeather));
        return fullWeather;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to SFSE. Please be aware that we have extensive resources available for introductory unit test questions, as well as hundreds of existing questions on our platform. Please do review all of the testing material you'll find under [canonical-qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-qa).

Comment: Please also be aware that SFSE always looks to see *what you've tried* in your questions. It is not a goal of our community to provide code or tests, but to help solve *specific problems*. You can learn more in [ask] and under [help/on-topic].